# not authorized to perform: aws-marketplace:ViewSubscriptions on resource: *

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have an IAM group, and policy "AWSMarketplaceFullAccess" is attached to it.

I confirmed that an IAM user belonging to that group is allowed to perform `AWS Marketplace.ViewSubscriptions`, using IAM Policy Simulator,
but that user still cannot boot EC2 instances from Marketplace images.

Error message is `User: arn:aws:iam::****:user/**** is not authorized to perform: aws-marketplace:ViewSubscriptions on resource: *`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/controlling-access/ControllingAccessToAWSMarketplaceSubscriptions.html) I have added Full access to the following policies for my AWS group:

```
Marketplace
Marketplace Metering
```

In order to subscribe to AMI.